# Manually created input is breaking model posting back values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, model-binding

I have the following ViewModel:

```
public class DataSyncViewModel
{
    public ConfigurableDataSyncOptions DataSyncOptions { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SystemName { get; set; }
}
```

I then loop through the `DataSyncOptions` to list some textboxes in my view:

```
@if (@Model.DataSyncOptions != null)
{
    if (Model.DataSyncOptions.TextConfigurableOptions != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.DataSyncOptions.TextConfigurableOptions.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="span6">
                <h4>@Model.DataSyncOptions.TextConfigurableOptions[i].OptionText?</h4>
                <p>
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.DataSyncOptions.TextConfigurableOptions[i].OptionValue)
                </p>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.DataSyncOptions.TextConfigurableOptions[i].OptionName)
            </div>
        }
    }
}
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SystemName)
```

This works and when the form posts back, I can access `SystemName` and `Id` from my controller.

**However**, if I replace

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.DataSyncOptions.TextConfigurableOptions[i].OptionValue)
```

with

```
@if (Model.DataSyncOptions.TextConfigurableOptions[i].OptionType == "")
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.DataSyncOptions.TextConfigurableOptions[i].OptionValue)

}
else
{
    //This appears to be causing issues
    <input type="@Model.DataSyncOptions.TextConfigurableOptions[i].OptionType" name="Model.DataSyncOptions.TextConfigurableOptions[@i].OptionValue" value="@Model.DataSyncOptions.TextConfigurableOptions[i].OptionValue" />
}
```

my values stop posting back with the model. I am trying to allow a plugin creator of my app to specify the input type of an option they have added so am creating the input manually.

Any ideas as to why changing the input generation breaks the model binding on postback?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Model` write Model Class Name in **name** attribute which is `DataSyncViewModel` to bind:

```
<input type="@Model.DataSyncOptions.TextConfigurableOptions[i].OptionType"
       name="DataSyncOptions.TextConfigurableOptions[@i].OptionValue"
       value="@Model.DataSyncOptions.TextConfigurableOptions[i].OptionValue" />
```

Actually when we write `@Model` it is in actualy the instance of type to which our View is strongly typed, and in this case Model is simple string not Razor so it will remain as **Model** and as name is different of input so it will not be binded to Model property in post.

Comment: Well, bugger. Now I feel silly. Thanks for your time. It was confusing me as it was posting back the actual value of the input but breaking the rest.

Comment: Had to remove answer mark on this. Changing my input inline with your code stops the value from this input posting back. It was posting back properly before but stopped other values. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: If the action method parameter is `(DataSyncViewModel model)` then the `name` attribute should be `DataSyncOptions.TextConfigurableOptions[@i].OptionValue` (strip the `DataSyncViewModel.` prefix)

Comment: @StephenMuecke good catch, you are right. webnoob you have to put it the way Stephen is saying